# How to set a breakpoint at the specific location on the stack in OllyDbg

Tags: ollydbg

Is there any way to set a breakpoint at the specific location on the stack in OllyDbg?

I have some value (argument of the function) on the stack and I want to break on every memory access at this location.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take the address, browse to it in the memory dump, right click -> breakpoint -> hardware, on access.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Take the offset of the stack place you wanna breakpoint at
- Go to memory dump, and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> (Go), and put the address there, and press <kbd>Ok</kbd>
- Right click the first value, and go to `Breakpoint` -> `Hardware, on access` -> [size]. A `Dword` is 4 bytes, which is how much bytes the stack viewer shows.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

If the arguments of the function on stack  is a pointer (such as `pThreadId` for `CreateThread`), then follow the steps below. Otherwise if the argument is some value (like `CreationFlags`) then refer to *AcidShout's* answer.

**1.** Right click on the address on the stack -> Chose *Follow in Dump*.
[image]

**2.** In the dump window, right click on the value -> *Breakpoint* -> H*ardware on access* -> *Byte / Word / Dword*

[image]